# Removing /profile/ from /profile/{username} keyword from Route Web.php does not work

Tags: laravel

I have a Route

```
Route::get('/{username}', 'ProfileController@profile')->name('profile.view');
```

If I keep it in the middle of the file, all the route after this does not work.

If I keep this in the bottom, then everything works.

Also, If I add any work like Profile, it works.

```
Route::get('profile/{username}', 'ProfileController@profile')->name('profile.view');
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way it is supposed to work as you are using a wildcard to match everything. So either you put it at the bottom of the file and it will be used as a fallback route, which means nothing above it should match, then it will fallback to that route. Or you can use a regex to match the username to something which makes it different then the other routes, something like:

```
Route::get('{username}', 'ProfileController@profile')
    ->name('profile.view')
    ->where('username', 'YOUR REGEX HERE');
```

I would go with the one you showed and already works:

```
Route::get('profile/{username}', 'ProfileController@profile')
    ->name('profile.view');

// or
Route::get('user/{username}', 'ProfileController@profile')
    ->name('profile.view');
```

Comment: Can i have a If clause to validate if there is no {username} then skip it?

Comment: I don't think so, not in the route file anyway. From the controller it will throw 404 if it is not matched to a user anyway. So the route model binding will do that for you.